# Unable to change clock separator

Tags: macos, system-settings, formatting, clock

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. In the `Language & Region` preferences, I clicked <kbd>Advanced</kbd> and set my clock format to <kbd>0-23</kbd>`:`<kbd>08</kbd>.
However, the clock in the menu bar and in the `Date & Time` preferences is displayed with the `.` separator instead of `:`. The dot seems to be the default for my language format (which is wrong, we use `:`). Furthermore, if I modify the contents of `com.apple.menuextra.clock.plist`, they are overridden as soon as I restart `SystemUIServer` or relogon. For example:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock DateFormat -string 'H:mm'
killall SystemUIServer
defaults read com.apple.menuextra.clock
```

results in

```
{
    DateFormat = "HH.mm";
    FlashDateSeparators = 0;
    IsAnalog = 0;
}
```

How can I change the clock separator?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by go to Language & Region and choose the region that has the same clock separator (I chose Australia) and then you can go to Advanced and customize your own dates and times format. Hope it helps

Comment: With this approach the day, month, etc. names are not in the correct language.